# TikZ: building closed path with \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikz-path

Programmatically constructing a closed path with tikz is easy:

```
\path (a0) \foreach \i in {1, ..., 7} {-- (a\i)} -- cycle;
```

But it forces to single out the first point. Reversing the construction pattern is rejected by tikz:

```
\path \foreach \i in {0, ..., 7} {(a\i) --} cycle;
```

and I suppose there are good reasons for that (I read an explanation about that on SE, but have lost reference to that answer *edit* found it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75152/102121)).

Unfortunately, if the building pattern is more complex than just adding point after point, the working solution can be quite tedious :

```
\path \foreach \i in {0, ..., 8} {(a\i) -- (\i*10:3) -- (b\i) --} cycle;
```

would be quite compact a way, but to get it to work I would need to code:

```
\path (a0) -- (0:3) -- (b0) \foreach \i in {0, ..., 8} {-- (a\i) -- (\i*10:3) -- (b\i)} -- cycle;
```

And that isn't even a complicated computation.

Is there some magic that would allow me to build the entire path using only `\foreach` ?

**EDIT**: example of such a construction

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[gray, rounded corners=25pt, even odd rule] (30:5) -- (120:3) -- (0:4) \foreach \i in {1, ...,19} {-- (30+18*\i:5) -- (120+18*\i:3) -- (18*\i:4)} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please provide small complete document (MWE) that we not need to write code from scratch ...

Comment: @Zarko I've added an example, though I need to stress that I am not looking for an ad-hoc solution for a given problem. I hope it is aesthetically pleasing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind adding some if's you can place the missing `--` here and there

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \fill[gray, rounded corners=25pt, even odd rule]  \foreach \i in {0,...,19} {
  \pgfextra{\ifnum\i=0\relax\else--\fi}
  (30+18*\i:5) -- (120+18*\i:3) -- (18*\i:4) 
  \pgfextra{\ifnum\i=0\relax--\fi}
} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Actually you can shorten those further but the gist is the same.

Comment: No I don't mind, and am very pleased with this solution. But it seems to me the second `pgfextra` is superflouous.

Comment: @ChristophFrings Might indeed be. To be honest didn't test it extensively.

Comment: Then I'll just keep the first one :) Thx for your inhumanly fast and pertinent answers.

Comment: @ChristophFrings The pleasure is mine

Comment: @percusse It looks strange to me this `\pgfextra{--}`, why you need it ? And when you draw it (something that you don't do, I know ;)) you can see that `rounded corners=25pt` are not applied to all corners.

Comment: @Kpym Probably screwed up due to the last `--`, I'll test when I have some TeX capability

Answer (score 2):

What you should know is that `foreach` body is executed in a group `{...}`. So this makes everything tricky. To avoid this problems you can use another loop like `\xintFor` from `xinttools` library, for example. Or you can do it in a tricky way :

```
\documentclass[border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \def\segment{(30:5) -- (120:3) -- (0:4)}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \fill[gray, rounded corners=25pt, even odd rule]
     \segment foreach \i in {0,...,20} {[rotate=\i*18] -- \segment} -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** If you want to draw it you can start from `1`, but if you want to fill it with `even odd rule`, it looks like you have to start from `0` and draw the first segment twice. But in this case there is some small problem in the beginning :(