# Iterate over part of a list

Tags: loops, comma-separated-list

I know that the package *etoolbox* has a \foreach command.

I want to set a list once an use it multiple times.
In the example, I would set \mylist equal to  the
comma separated value list 10,20,30,40,50.

I want to have a command like

```
\forparteach 3 \var \in {10,20,30, 40,50} {
  \var
}
```

is the same as

```
\foreach \var \in {10,20,30} {
   \var
}
```

Or even

```
\forparteach {1,3,4,2,5,5} \var \in {10,20,30,40,50} {
   \var
}
```

is the same as

```
\foreach \var \in {10,30,40,20,50,50} {
   \var
}
```

Is there any package out there that does this or an easy solution?

Thanks!

Comment: How would you distinguish between `\forparteach 3` picking every third element and not just the (single) 3rd element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the things can be achieved with the current `\foreach` in a straightforward way. More specifically, `\breakforeach` allows you to break a loop, which allows you to restrict the loop to the first `n` entries. And you can store the list in an array and access its elements.  Notice that I did not even try to write a new macro `\forparteach` because `\foreach` is very delicate and I do not dare to mess around with it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\section*{Cutting a loop off at some number}
\foreach \var [count=\n] in {10,20,30,40,50} 
{ \var 
\ifnum\n>2 
\breakforeach 
\fi
}
\section*{Selecting a subset of items from a list/an array}
\def\myarray{{10,20,30,40,50}}
\foreach \var [evaluate=\var as \myindex using {int(\var-1)}] in {1,3,4,2,5,5} {
\pgfmathparse{\myarray[\myindex]}\pgfmathresult
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own foreach cycle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xforeach}{sO{}mm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \marks_xforeach:Vnn #3 { #2 } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \marks_xforeach:nnn { #3 } { #2 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\keys_define:nn { marks/xforeach }
 {
  upto  .int_set:N   = \l_marks_xforeach_upto_int,
  items .clist_set:N = \l_marks_xforeach_items_clist,
 }

\clist_new:N \l__marks_xforeach_main_clist
\seq_new:N \l__marks_xforeach_items_seq
\seq_new:N \l__marks_xforeach_main_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marks_xforeach:nnn
 {
  \clist_set:Nn \l__marks_xforeach_main_clist { #1 }
  \keys_set:nn { marks/xforeach } { upto=-1, items=, #2 }
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__marks_xforeach_cycle:n { #3 }

  \seq_clear:N \l__marks_xforeach_items_seq
  \clist_if_empty:NTF \l_marks_xforeach_items_clist
   {% items not specified
    \int_compare:nT { \l_marks_xforeach_upto_int = -1 }
     {
      \int_set:Nn \l_marks_xforeach_upto_int
       { \clist_count:N \l__marks_xforeach_main_clist }
     }
    \int_step_inline:nn { \l_marks_xforeach_upto_int }
     {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \l__marks_xforeach_items_seq { ##1 }
     }
   }
   {% items
    \seq_set_from_clist:NN \l__marks_xforeach_items_seq \l_marks_xforeach_items_clist
   }
  \seq_clear:N \l__marks_xforeach_main_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__marks_xforeach_items_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__marks_xforeach_main_seq
     {
      \clist_item:Nn \l__marks_xforeach_main_clist { ##1 }
     }
   }
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__marks_xforeach_main_seq \__marks_xforeach_cycle:n
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \marks_xforeach:nnn { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myarray}{10,20,30,40,50}

\xforeach{10,20,30,40,50}{(Item: #1) }

\xforeach*{\myarray}{(Item: #1) }

\xforeach[upto=3]{10,20,30,40,50}{(Item: #1) }

\xforeach*[upto=3]{\myarray}{(Item: #1) }

\xforeach[items={1,3,4,2,5,5}]{10,20,30,40,50}{(Item: #1) }

\xforeach*[items={1,3,4,2,5,5}]{\myarray}{(Item: #1) }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some points to note: differently from `\foreach`, the cycles are not performed in groups; the current item is denoted by `#1` rather than by designating a macro holding it. The *-variant accepts as second argument a macro instead of an explicit list.

One could rely on the presence of braces like `\foreach`, but in my opinion using options and specific commands is cleaner.

Comment: +1. This looks like a promising alternative to the `\foreach` that comes with `pgffor`. Do you think it is possible to define a `cousin` of the standard `\foreach` this way, which does not produce a lot of groups? I am asking this because that may help in some situations like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449918/121799). Of course, I will be happy to ask a separate question on this if you feel that's more appropriate.

Comment: @marmot Something like in [this paper](https://www.guitex.org/home/images/ArsTeXnica/AT022/gregorio.pdf)?

Comment: Si, signore. Except that I am wondering if it is possible to recreate all the nice things of `\foreach` like `\foreach \X in {1,3,...,17,18,19}`, `\foreach \X,\Y in {1/red,2/blue,3/green}` and also the `evaluate`, `count` and remember keys. Ho mangiato pizza senza pineapple.

Comment: @marmot I don't like the syntax of `\foreach`. The `evaluate` and so on things are in a long term program. The double variable cycles are already implemented, if you look better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do these things with `xinttools`. The `\xintFor/\xintFor*` loops do not create groups. On the other hand, they do not currently implement some nice `\foreach` syntax like `1, 2, ..., 5`. And there is no easy way to create `key=value` selection as `xinttools` is not a full-fledged programming interface like provided by LaTeX3, but a small collection of useful macros (usable under Plain TeX, too).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xinttools}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}\thispagestyle{empty}

\section*{Cutting a loop off at some number}

First three:

\begin{itemize}
% this uses \xintFor* as argument will be {item1}{item2}....
% i.e. a "list" in the sense of xinttools doc, not a
% "comma separated list"
 \xintFor* #1 in {\xintKeep{3}{\xintCSVtoList{10,20,30,40,50}}}
 \do 
  {\item (Item: #1)}
\end{itemize}

Last two:

\begin{itemize}
 \xintFor* #1 in {\xintKeep{-2}{\xintCSVtoList{10,20,30,40,50}}}
 \do 
  {\item (Item: #1)}
\end{itemize}

Trim first two:

\begin{itemize}
 \xintFor* #1 in {\xintTrim{2}{\xintCSVtoList{10,20,30,40,50}}}
 \do 
  {\item (Item: #1)}
\end{itemize}

Trim last two:

\begin{itemize}
 \xintFor* #1 in {\xintTrim{-2}{\xintCSVtoList{10,20,30,40,50}}}
 \do 
  {\item (Item: #1)}
\end{itemize}

Nested keep/trim (keep 2 after having trimmed 2):

\begin{itemize}
 \xintFor* #1 in {\xintKeep{2}{\xintTrim{2}{\xintCSVtoList{10,20,30,40,50}}}}
 \do 
  {\item (Item: #1)}
\end{itemize}


\clearpage
\section*{Selecting a subset of items from a list}

Selecting items 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 5:

% for better efficiency, let's convert comma separated values
% in a "list" (in xinttools terminology) first, once and for all
% because \xintNthElt macro expects such as list

\oodef\MyListOfBracedItems{\xintCSVtoList{10,20,30,40,50}}

\begin{itemize}
% this uses the non-starred \xintFor, which accepts comma separated values
 \xintFor #1 in {1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 5}
 \do 
  {\item (Item: \xintNthElt{#1}{\MyListOfBracedItems})}
\end{itemize}

It is also possible to create an ``array'', for better efficiency afterwards:

\xintAssignArray\xintCSVtoList{10, 20, 30, 40, 50}\to\MyArray

\begin{itemize}
% this uses the starred \xintFor, which accepts braced items (or
% single tokens; spaces skipped)
 \xintFor* #1 in {1 3 4 2 5 5}
 \do 
  {\item (Item: \MyArray{#1})}
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Page 1

[image]

Page 2

[image]

Comment: I did not incorporate in my answer the fact that Python slicing notation is implemented in `xintexpr`: `\xinttheexpr [10, 20, 30, 40, 50][2:4]\relax` for example will expand to `30, 40`. Indeed it will be usable only for (floating-point) numbers. One can also do `\xinttheexpr subs(seq([L][i], i=0,2,3,1,4,4), L=10, 20, 30, 40, 50)\relax` or `\xinttheexpr seq([(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)][i], i=0,2,3,1,4,4)\relax` but the former is more efficient and did not need the extra parenthesis pair to hide commas from `seq`. Syntax is nice, but works only with numbers. Completely expandable!