# Using foreachitem inside a \draw command

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to dynamically construct a `\draw` command inside a tikz picture like this:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black,thick] (0,0)--(0,-10)--(0,10)--cycle;

    \readlist*\mylist{-10,10}

    % This line attempts to mimic the above \draw dynamically, but it fails
    %\draw[black,thick] (0,0)--{\foreachitem\x\in\mylist[]{\ifnum\xcnt>1\ -- \else\ \fi(0,\x)}}--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, this fails to compile with a slew of errors, including this one:

```
tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate
```

How can I dynamically construct a draw like this that ends with a cycle? I know this MWE is kinda dumb right now because it's just a straight line, but if I can solve this then I can achieve my actual goal.

## Update

I made some progress using @marmot's suggestion of using `foreach`, but unfortunately I hit the same problem again when trying to apply it to my actual use case, which is this:

```
% args:
% 1 = draw style
% 2 = value count
% 3 = list of values (comma-separated)
\newcommand{\band}[3]{
    % I want to achieve something like this (assuming arg #2 = 3, and arg #3 = 1,2,3)
    \draw[#1] (360/3:1) -- (360/3*2:2) -- (360/3*3:3) --cycle;

    % But this fails    
    %\draw[#1] foreach [count=\xi] \X in {#3} { (360/3*\xi:\X) -- }cycle;
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you do not just a normal `foreach` here? (This is not a criticism, really just a question. ;-)

Comment: `\draw[black,thick]  (0,0) foreach \X  in {-10,10}
 { --  (0,\X)}--cycle;` or `\draw[black,thick]  plot[samples at={0,-10,10}] (0,\x) --cycle;` do what I think you want to do.

Comment: @marmot Mainly ignorance. It's being used in an environment. I need the caller to be able to pass in any number of coordinates via a single parameter, which I will split at commas using the `listofitems` package.

Comment: I just played around with `foreach` and was able to get it working based on your suggestion. It's even cleaner now than using `listofitems` so that's great!

Comment: @marmot Actually, I'm back where I started when I tried to apply this to my actual problem. See my question update.

Comment: I see. I was playing basket ball till now. You are facing the problem of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449918/121799), which is not directly related to foreach vs. foreachitem vs. you-know-not. There are IMHO two independent questions. One is on all these expansion issues and one is what is the easiest way to draw something through a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, the `\draw` command doesn't like the `listofitem` calculations inside of its arguments.  The alternative here is to save the desired tokens in a token list and then out put the token list clean, after all the calculations are done.

I introduce two macros, `\addpathtoks{}` to add literal tokens to the path, and `\xaddpathtoks`, to expand (once) the first token in argument and add the result to the path.  The expand part is needed to turn the `\x` into an actual number.

**UPDATED ANSWER** to updated question

Note the black triangle is done via `\band` macro, the dashed yellow (overlaying) triangle is done manually.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newtoks\pathtoks
\newcommand\addpathtoks[1]{%
  \pathtoks\expandafter{\the\pathtoks#1}}
\newcommand\xaddpathtoks[1]{%
  \expandafter\addpathtoks\expandafter{#1}}

\newcommand{\band}[3]{
\readlist*\mylist{#3}
\pathtoks{}
\foreachitem\x\in\mylist[]{%
  \ifnum\xcnt=1\relax \addpathtoks{\draw#1}\else
    \addpathtoks{--}
  \fi
  \addpathtoks{(360/}\addpathtoks{#2*}%
  \xaddpathtoks{\x:}\xaddpathtoks{\x)}
  \ifnum\xcnt=\listlen\mylist[]\relax\addpathtoks{--cycle;}\fi
}
\the\pathtoks
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\band{[black,thick]}{3}{1,2,3}
\draw[yellow,thin,dashed] (360/3:1) -- (360/3*2:2) -- (360/3*3:3) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See **SUPPLEMENT** for possible improvement.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** to original question

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newtoks\pathtoks
\newcommand\addpathtoks[1]{%
  \pathtoks\expandafter{\the\pathtoks#1}}
\newcommand\xaddpathtoks[1]{%
  \expandafter\addpathtoks\expandafter{#1}}
\begin{document}
   \readlist*\mylist{-10,10}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black,thick] (0,0)--(0,-10)--(0,10)--cycle;

\pathtoks{}
\foreachitem\x\in\mylist[]{%
  \ifnum\xcnt=1\relax \addpathtoks{\draw[black,thick] (1,0)}\fi
  \addpathtoks{--(1,}\xaddpathtoks{\x)}%
  \ifnum\xcnt=\listlen\mylist[]\relax\addpathtoks{--cycle;}\fi
}
\the\pathtoks

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**SUPPLEMENT**

If I understand what is actually being done here, one may be able to get away with two, rather than three, arguments to `\band`, if it is always the case that the original `#2` will always be the list length of `#3`.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newtoks\pathtoks
\newcommand\addpathtoks[1]{%
  \pathtoks\expandafter{\the\pathtoks#1}}
\newcommand\xaddpathtoks[1]{%
  \expandafter\addpathtoks\expandafter{#1}}
\newcommand\xxaddpathtoks[1]{%
  \expandafter\xaddpathtoks\expandafter{#1}}

\newcommand{\band}[2]{
\readlist*\mylist{#2}
\pathtoks{}
\foreachitem\x\in\mylist[]{%
  \ifnum\xcnt=1\relax \addpathtoks{\draw#1}\else
    \addpathtoks{--}
  \fi
  \addpathtoks{(360/}\xxaddpathtoks{\listlen\mylist[]*}%
  \xaddpathtoks{\x:}\xaddpathtoks{\x)}
  \ifnum\xcnt=\listlen\mylist[]\relax\addpathtoks{--cycle;}\fi
}
\the\pathtoks
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\band{[black,thick]}{1,2,3}
\draw[yellow,thin,dashed] (360/3:1) -- (360/3*2:2) -- (360/3*3:3) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic answer and evidence I will _never_ understand LaTeX. Thank you so much!

Comment: If I need to have `{` and `}` in my token output, how can I do that? It works if the opening and closing braces are in the same `\addpathtoks` call, but not if I need to have an opening in one and closing in another (because I have a `\xaddpathtoks` in between).

Comment: @me-- Let's say you needed `\x` inside a brace added to the token list, you would use `\xaddpathtoks{\expandafter{\x}}`.  Since the `x` expands the first item in the list, which is `\expandafter`.  That in turn expands `\x` into a number, while leaving it inside the brace pair.  The only limitation is that the complete brace pair has to be added to the token list at once...you can't add a left brace in one moment and then a right brace separately.

Comment: @me-- If you really needed to add them `{}` to the token list far apart, there is another way to get there with the token list.  But that would be worthy of a new question.

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to get `\xcnt` into the token list, but the actual value rather than the token.

Comment: Here's the problematic line: `\addpathtoks{#2+0.5)node{\labellist[\xcnt]};}%`. The `\xcnt` is not being evaluated until later, when I really need it evaluated now. But if I try to break apart this line it fails because I need to break it after `node{` and before the closing `}`.

Comment: @me-- Is `\labellist[\xcnt]` a list that you read?  If so, `\addpathtoks{#2+0.5)node}\xxaddpathtoks{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\labellist[\xcnt]};}`.  This is because unlike `\x` which requires one expansion, `\labellist[]` requires two expansions.

Answer (score 3):

Your updated question is very closely related to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449918/121799), where nearly (?) identical difficulties have been reported. The upshot is, as explained by Paul Gaborit in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449918/foreach-path-operation-confused-about-syntax#comment1131122_449918) that

> Each iteration of foreach is a (TeX) group. You can't write \draw
>   {(0,0) --} (0,1); but you can write \draw (0,0) { -- (0,1)};

There are various ways to make it work. The essential trick is that you expand the foreach before `\draw` sees it. (`pgfplots` has a `\pgfplotsinvokeforeachungrouped` for precisely this purpose and there other means to achieve that.) Here is a primitive yet short and working way, which does not require any packages beyond Ti*k*Z, which you are using anyway.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
% args:
% 1 = draw style
% 2 = value count
% 3 = list of values (comma-separated)
\tikzset{my foreach code/.code={\xdef\Lst{}\foreach #1 }}
\newcommand{\band}[3][]{
    % I want to achieve something like this (assuming arg #2 = 3, and arg #3 = 1,2,3)
    %\draw[#1] (360/3:1) -- (360/3*2:2) -- (360/3*3:3) --cycle;

    \draw[#1,my foreach code={\X [count=\xi] in {#3} {\xdef\Lst{\Lst (360/3*\xi:\X) -- }}}] 
      \Lst   cycle;;
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \band{3}{1,2,3}
    \band[red]{3}{5,7,9}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me stress that if you just want to draw these triangles and do insist on having a loop over atoms of the form `(coordinate) --` then there are much simpler ways. Here is an example.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[band/.style={insert path={plot[samples at={0,1,2}]
    ({360/(\x+1)}:{#1}[\x]) -- cycle}}]
  \draw[band={1,2,3}];
  \draw[red,band={5,4,3}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is supposed to illustrate two points:

- You do not need to do all these `\newcommand`s, Ti*k*Z allows you to do pretty much everything with styles.
- You seem to re-invent plot handlers.