# Command not producing expected output

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is a follow-on question from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495556/using-foreachitem-inside-a-draw-command#495559). Things are *almost* working but something strange is going on with my `\band` command. It renders the first band correctly, but then the second band causes things to go haywire.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\begin{document}

\newtoks\pathtoks
\newcommand\addpathtoks[1]{%
    \pathtoks\expandafter{\the\pathtoks#1}}
\newcommand\xaddpathtoks[1]{%
    \expandafter\addpathtoks\expandafter{#1}}
\newcommand\xxaddpathtoks[1]{%
    \expandafter\xaddpathtoks\expandafter{#1}}

\newcommand{\band}[2]{
    \readlist*\valuelist{#2}
    \pathtoks{}
    \foreachitem\x\in\valuelist[]{%
        \ifnum\xcnt=1\relax \addpathtoks{\draw[#1]}\else
            \addpathtoks{--}
        \fi
        \addpathtoks{(360/}\xxaddpathtoks{\listlen\valuelist[]*}%
        \xaddpathtoks{\x:}\xaddpathtoks{\x)}
        \ifnum\xcnt=\listlen\valuelist[]\relax\addpathtoks{--cycle;}\fi
    }

    \the\pathtoks
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % This is what I expect the below \band invocations to produce, and this renders correctly.
    \draw[red] (360/3:1) -- (360/3*2:2) -- (360/3*3:3) --cycle;
    \draw[blue] (360/3:3) -- (360/3*2:2) -- (360/3*3:1) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % These bands, which should be equivalent to the above are not rendering correctly.
    \band{red}{1,2,3};
    \band{blue}{3,2,1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This renders like this:

[image]

The top picture is what I'd expect, but the bottom seems to re-render the same shape over the top of the existing one.

Weirder still, if two values are the same:

```
\band{red}{2,3,3};
```

It renders a straight line:

[image]

And if all three values are the same, it renders nothing at all! It's like it's de-duplicating the list...?

So my questions are:

1. Why does my repro above render the same triangle twice instead of the expected triangles?
2. Why do duplicate values cause weird things to happen?

## Update

My requirements are:

1. Being able to specify any number of values in the band and having the band automatically place those values that distance from the center of a circle, with each value being placed an equal number of degrees apart.
2. Being able to invoke this `band` command/environment/whatever it is with varying numbers of values and with different styles for the band.
3. Be able to compose whatever this `band` thing ends up being into an environment so I can do something like:

```
\begin{thething}
    \band{red}{1,3,2}
    \band{blue}{1,2,4}
\end{thething}

\begin{thething}
    \band{green}{5,3,4,1}
    \band{yellow}{1,1,4,5}
\end{thething}
```

The `thething` environment (which I believe I already have working) adds the requisite `tikzpicture` along with some default rendering. In reality, `thething` takes a list of labels to render - one for each value in the bands. The `band` calls then add to that rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ti*k*Z has all the means built in to simplify this quite a bit. All these macros can be absorbed in a simple style

```
band/.style={insert path={plot[samples at={0,1,2}]
    ({360/3*(\x+1)}:{#1}[\x]) -- cycle}}
```

with which you only need to say

```
\draw[red,band={1,2,3}];
```

You *could* make this a macro, but this would make it less powerful.
MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[band/.style={insert path={plot[samples at={0,1,2}]
    ({360/3*(\x+1)}:{#1}[\x]) -- cycle}},font=\sffamily]

  \begin{scope}[xshift=-5cm,local bounding box=by hand]
    \draw[red] (360/3:1) -- (360/3*2:2) -- (360/3*3:3) --cycle;
    \draw[blue] (360/3:3) -- (360/3*2:2) -- (360/3*3:1) --cycle;
  \end{scope}   
  \node[above=1ex] at (by hand.north){by hand};
  %
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=automatic]
    \draw[red,band={1,2,3}];
    \draw[blue,band={3,2,1}];
  \end{scope}   
  \node[above=1ex] at (automatic.north){automatic};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is easy to generalize it to something that takes an arbitrary number of arguments.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[band/.style={/utils/exec={\foreach \dummy[count=\cnt
starting from 0] in {#1} {\xdef\cnt{\cnt}}},
insert path={plot[samples at={0,...,\cnt}]
    ({360/(\cnt+1)*(\x+1)}:{#1}[\x]) -- cycle}},font=\sffamily]

  \begin{scope}[xshift=-5cm,local bounding box=by hand]
    \draw[red] (360/3:1) -- (360/3*2:2) -- (360/3*3:3) --cycle;
    \draw[blue] (360/3:3) -- (360/3*2:2) -- (360/3*3:1) --cycle;
  \end{scope}   
  \node[above=1ex] at (by hand.north){by hand};
  %
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=automatic]
    \draw[red,band={1,2,3}];
    \draw[blue,band={3,2,1}];
    \draw[orange,band={3,2,1,4,3,5}];
  \end{scope}   
  \node[above=1ex] at (automatic.north){automatic};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to embed the number of allowed values into the style...? I wanted the flexibility of passing in a list of values and having it just work regardless of how many.

Comment: I updated my question and just saw your response. Trying it now.

Comment: Actually, no. The problem will be the `#1` because I am trying to use it inside an environment and that seems not to work.

Comment: @me-- There is the standard thingy that you need to add `#`. This has nothing to do with the solution here. And you can define a new command `\newcommand{\band}[2][]{\draw[#1,band={#2}]}` so if newcommand works this will wor.

Comment: Oh wow, I think it's actually working. I feel completely mystified by how this all works, but thanks very much for the help @marmot!