# Filling (continuous) Path using \foreach with complex calculations for each point

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, fill

I am trying to draw a curve by calculating every point's position in a `\foreach` loop (potentially hundreds of points).
Since the calculation is quite complex, I use `\pgfmathsetmacro` multiple times to store intermediate results.

Here is a MWE of what I currently have. It draws the path I want it to, but it is not a continuous path, so I can't easily fill it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \foreach \t in {0.0,0.1,...,1}{
            % complex calculation depending on \t here with lots of \pgfmathsetmacro s
            % The values of the pos variables obviously depend on the previous calculations in my actual use case
            \pgfmathsetmacro \posX {\t}
            \pgfmathsetmacro \posY {\t * \t}
            \pgfmathsetmacro \posXNext {\t + 0.1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro \posYNext {(\t + 0.1) * (\t + 0.1)}
            \draw (\posX, \posY) -- (\posXNext, \posYNext);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I can't use the solution suggested here:
[Draw a path between many nodes using foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75146/draw-a-path-between-many-nodes-using-foreach), because of all the `\pgfmathsetmacro`s before the `\draw` call (or at least I couldn't get it to work).

Here is an image of the result of the MWE and what I would like to achieve:

[image: MWE output]
[image: goal]

If there is a completely different way of doing this, that's ok too.

Thanks.

Comment: In a single path (`\draw...`), you can call `\pgfextra{...}` to do calculation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by Paul and the post I mentioned in the original question ([Draw a path between many nodes using foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75146/draw-a-path-between-many-nodes-using-foreach)), I found an answer that suits my needs (The bug mentioned in the linked post is probably fixed by now, as I don't need the definition that's mentioned there):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=red!50!white] (0, 0)
        \foreach \t in {0.0,0.1,...,1}{
            \pgfextra
                % complex calculation depending on \t here with lots of \pgfmathsetmacro s
                \pgfmathsetmacro \x {\t}
                \pgfmathsetmacro \y {\t * \t}
            \endpgfextra
             -- (\x, \y)
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Thanks Paul!

Answer (score 4):

An arguably simpler way is to use `plot` along with `samples at`. Ti*k*Z parses the coordinates for you.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=red!50!white] (0, 0) --
        plot[samples at={0.0,0.1,...,1},variable=\t] 
        ({\t},{\t * \t});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Ti*k*Z automatically parses its coordinates, there is no need to use `\pgfmathsetmacro`. Let's now assume you have a more complex function. Then you could just store its definition in the declaration of a function.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\t)=\t*\t-0.1*pow(\t,3)-0.1*\t*exp(-\t*\t);}]
        \draw[fill=red!50!white] (0, 0) --
        plot[samples at={0.0,0.1,...,1},variable=\t] 
        ({\t},{f(\t)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You may or may not want to add `smooth` to your function. Note also that there is the option `/tikz/parametric` which can be found on p. 339 of the pgfmanual version 3.1.1, which invokes gnuplot to plot a parametric function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It definitely looks a lot simpler, but is it possible to add some `\pgfmathsetmacro`s (or smth. like that) which depend on `\t`?
The computation of the actual curve I am drawing is a lot more complex than `t^2`, too complex to put it in one line and still understand it in a couple of weeks ^^

Comment: @Nathanael Ti*k*Z parses the coordinates. You can store any complicated function in a function that you declare, e.g. `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\t)=\t*\t-0.1*pow(\t,3)-0.1*\t*exp(-\t*\t);}]
        \draw[fill=red!50!white] (0, 0) --
        plot[samples at={0.0,0.1,...,1},variable=\t] 
        ({\t},{f(\t)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Comment: Didn't know about these functions, still fairly new to tikz/pgf...
I guess I could put it all in a function like that, but it's not really as readable anymore. If you are curious, thats my actual code atm: https://pastebin.com/G79ab1xF
I would like to keep these "variables".

Comment: @Nathanael For some reason your link is empty but you can nest functions, i.e. declare two functions `f` and `g` and compute `f(g(\x))` and declare functions of several variables and so on. I personally find this much more readable than many `\pgfmathsetmacro`s.

Comment: Strange, maybe this one works: https://pastebin.com/nCb5KtJC
I guess with nesting it would work, thanks for the elaboration!

Comment: @Nathanael You could put all this into a `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`, see section **95 Customizing the Mathematical Engine** of the newest version of the pgfmanual.

Comment: That looks very promising. I will look into it the next time I need something like that. At the moment it works as it is.
In case you are wondering: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_Catmull%E2%80%93Rom_spline , that's what I am drawing (with variable alpha).
Thanks again, greatly appreciated!